# Find out what's causing high server load?

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, whm

If a server has become inaccessible via SSH due to high load, I would usually restart it.

How do you usually find out the cause of the high load (e.g., what process, how much RAM/CPU was used, etc.)?

I am using WHM / Cpanel.

Answer (score -1):

1. install collectd.
2. try to `ssh 192.168.1.1 killall -9 httpd`
   OR  `rsh 192.168.1.1 killall -9 httpd` instead of reboot,
   thus you will save a time.
3. also you can use htop. It can show statistic from boot time.
4. check httpd logs and syslog